# Significance of encoding scheme in Genetic Algorithms

Tags: optimization

In the basic structure of a genetic algorithm, we have a population which is iteratively changed via **selection**, **crossover**, and **mutation**. Roughly:

- **selection** biases the procedure towards individuals with high fitness,
- **crossover** combines individuals to generate new individuals,
- **mutation** perturbs individuals to generate new individuals which may be completely foreign to what's been seen before.

Intuitively, as an optimization routine, a prerequisite to making this effective should be some assumption of smoothness in the fitness landscape (the function from encoded string to fitness value). Without that assumption (and considering each step separately) *[1]*:

- **selection** would function like a random search/random sampling,
- **crossover** would send you to an arbitrary location in the landscape, with no guarantees that a combination of parents actually takes any of their (desirable or not) traits,
- **mutation** would not necessary give you a neighbor of your parent (in the fitness sense or even in the sense of having mostly similar traits) - again it can send you to a random location in the landscape.

So without that smoothness assumption, it seems none of the operations are any better than random search/random sampling. Admittedly, any kind of non-exhaustive optimization routine implicitly or otherwise makes at least some smoothness assumptions (simulated annealing and hill climbing both assume neighbors of current state should have closer objective value than a random candidate). What's interesting in the case of a genetic algorithm is that we do not directly operate on the parameters - so there is a chance for/a requirement that the encoding scheme is designed such that the fitness landscape is smooth.

I haven't seen any explicit mention of this idea in the theory. Is this actually a concern? If so, should we be designing encoding schemes so that there's a higher chance that crossover and mutation produce true "neighbors" of their inputs?

*[1] I'm aware that the Schema Theorem implies the entire procedure works differently, and does not necessarily require any short of "neighbor" relationship be maintained across the operators. However, it seems even that idea requires some structure from the schemas: "11**" ought to be closer to "1***" than to "0***", but one can imagine a encoding where that's not the case; additionally, "11**" appear equidistant to "10**" and "01**", but in the case where the first digit represents a trait and the second a parameter of the trait, "10**" would be a true neighbor but "01**" would be completely unrelated.*

Comment: Richard Dawkins' "Climbing Mount Improbable" has an extensive discussion of the impacts of the fitness landscape on evolution.  It is oriented toward living things, but the ideas apply.  He talks about the differences between a large smooth plain and a mountainous landscape in detail.

Comment: Natural selection is one of nature's most formidable design tools.